# apply a formula to an imported range in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a spreadsheet in Google Sheets that's using an endpoint to populate with `=importxml()` 
When pasting a formula on a column of the imported data, the import does not load.
How can I get a formula to apply to a column of the imported data?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: @map.apps You should be aware that sharing your spreadsheet will unavoidably expose your email address.